# What's a good bit of JS or JQuery for horizontally scrolling news ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, client-side

I am looking for a little bit of JQuery or JS that allows me to produce a horizontally scrolling "news ticker" list.

The produced HTML needs to be standards compliant as well.

I have tried [liScroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html) but this has a habit of breaking (some content ends up on a second line at the start of the scroll), especially with longer lists.

I have also tried [this News Ticker](http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/newsticker_javascript.htm) but when a DOCTYPE is included the scrolling will jolt rather than cycle smoothly at the end of each cycle.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit**

So thanks to Matt Hinze's suggestion I realised I could do what I wanted to do with JQuery animate (I require continuous scrolling not discrete scrolling like the example). However, I quickly ran into similar problems to those I was having with liScroll and after all that realised a CSS issue (as always) was responsible.

Solution: liScroll - change the default 'var stripWidth = 0' to something like 100, to give a little space and avoid new line wrapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smooth Div Scroll can also be used as a news ticker/stock ticker. It can pause on mouse over or mouse down and it can loop endlessly if you want it to.

Here's [the example](http://www.maaki.com/) with a running ticker.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.emrecamdere.com/news_scroller_jquery.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's 2 other solutions that seem a bit simpler to implement:

1. [newsticker](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/newsticker/)
2. [News ticker (BBC style)](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/BBCnewsTicker)

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative solution would also be the [jQuery webTicker](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/); its very similar to liscroll however resolves the problem with the ticker stopping after the whole list completes; whilst also adding some new fancy features like; direction of movement; speed; and ability to use multiple tickers per page.

Answer (score 0):

The second line bug arising in liscroll can be "fixed" by adding a listitem containing a non-breakable space entitiy `<li>&nbsp;</li>` at the end of each list ;)