# jQuery.ScrollTo / jQuery.SerialScroll Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: jquery, scrollto, serialscroll

I am looking to implement horizontal scrolling using [jQuery.SerialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) (based on [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)).

I currently have a continuous horizontal scrolling working with liScroll as I discuss in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027/whats-a-good-bit-of-js-or-jquery-for-horizontally-scrolling-news-ticker).

However, now I need discrete scrolling and I have SerialScroll working perfectly for vertical scrolling.

For some reason, if the 'axis' property is specified as 'x' nothing happens.

I can't even get the [SerialScroll example for right to left scrolling](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/SerialScroll_right-to-left.js) to work.

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="pane">
   <div>Item 1</div>
   <div>Item 2</div>
   <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

I have jQuery like this, that works when axis is 'y'

```
 jQuery(function($) {
      var $pane = $('#pane');
      $pane.serialScroll({
          items: 'div',
          next: $pane, // the container itself will get bound
          duration: 2100,
          force: true,
          axis: 'x',
          step: 1, //scroll 1 news each time
          event: 'showNext' //just a random event name
       });

       setInterval(function() {//scroll each 12 seconds
          $pane.trigger('showNext');
       }, 12000);
   });
```

Any ideas?

//Edit (answer accepted)

For those that come along, the accepted answer gets rid of the need for "serialScroll" (just need scrollTo). Heights weren't required. Be sure to change $('scroller') to something like $('mywrap') or $(target.parent().parent()). You can also set up automatic scrolling like this:

```
 var index = 2;

 setInterval(function() {//scroll each 5 seconds
 index = index > $('#news ul li').length ? 1 : index;
  sliderScroll($('#news ul li:nth-child(' + index + ')'));
  index ++;
 }, 5000);
```

replacing #news ul li to your appropriate selector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was recently working with scrollTo to implement a Coda-like slider wizard.

Here's the steps I took:

1. Set a containing div to the dimensions I wanted the slider to appear as. overflow:auto; helps for testing, but you'll probably want to use overflow:hidden in the end.
2. Inside that place another div, make it big enough to hold all your elements horizontally.
3. Float the panels. give them explicit dimensions.

My CSS:

```
.scroller{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 410px;
  width: 787px;}
  .modal-content{width: 3400px;}
    .modal-content div{float:left; width:728px; height: 405px; padding: 0 30px;}
```

My JS:

```
function sliderScroll(target){
  if(target.length <1)return false;
  $(".current").removeClass("current");
  target.addClass("current");
  $(".scroller").scrollTo(target,500,{axis:'x'});
  return false;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <div>...</div>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! - For those interested please see my edits in the question for some minor modifications.