# uptodate marquee

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax, jquery

I have a marquee tag that shows news from my database
I want to make this marquee uptodate without refreshing the page
so I used ajax (update_panel + timer) to do that but the problem that
the marquee doesn't revolve after the timer is working

Notice:
My marquee is a literal(component)
and I put my text with marquee tags inside the literal.
Do you have any idea about this problem ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Avoid using marquees for news scrolling.

Comment: thanks phoenix
I want some thing to scroll
because I want to show security prices in this marquee
so do you know any thing else that revolve like the marquee

Comment: Edited to add the jQuery tags, to hopefully bring in some more experienced folks than myself.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by phoenix, in the comments to the question, don't use the `<marquee>` tag. If you're able to go with a jQuery solution there's quite a few news-tickers on offer, including this one: [jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html).

---

Edited, it might be worth taking a read of this thread for insights into some of the problems/solutions related to news tickers: [What's a good bit of js or jQuery for a horizontally-scrolling news ticker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027/whats-a-good-bit-of-js-or-jquery-for-horizontally-scrolling-news-ticker)?

---

Edited, in response to the OP's question in the comments.

Using jQuery and Ajax doesn't seem to be particularly difficult or contra-indicated, if you look at the results page for '[jQuery + ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery+ajax)' there's a significant number of results, suggesting that the two go together. Admittedly, the number of results may indicate difficulties, too. But I'm afraid I can't help much, since I've never tried to couple the two together. Or used Ajax at all so far...sorry.

Comment: but is this thing up to date
I mean can I use ajax with jQuery